# Failed to produce diagnostic for expression using $viewModel

Tags: swift, swiftui, binding, combine

I have a Picker in a child view:

```
struct EventPickerView: View {
    @Binding private(set) var selection: String
    @State var labelText: String
    @State var pickerData: [String]
    
    init(
        pickerData: [String],
        selection: Binding<String>,
        labelText: String
    ) {
        self.pickerData = pickerData
        self.labelText = labelText
        self._selection = selection
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                Text(labelText)
                    .font(.headline)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                Spacer()
                Picker(selection: $selection) {
                   ForEach(pickerData, id: \.self) { 
                   item in
                     Text(item)
                   }
                } label: {
                }
                
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .accentColor(.white)
            }
            .padding(5)
        }
    }
}
```

which is added to a parentView like so:

```
struct AddEventView<ViewModel: AddEventViewModeling & ObservableObject>: View {
    
@ObservedObject var viewModel: ViewModel
    
init(viewModel: ViewModel) {
    self.viewModel = viewModel
}

   @ViewBuilder
   var body: some View {
   VStack {
          // other views 
          EventPickerView(pickerData: viewModel.eventCreatingPickerFields?.eventParticipants ?? [String](), selection: $viewModel.fieldType, labelText: "Match Type")            
         // other stuff
      }
   }
}
```

in my viewModel I have a `@Published` var which I would like to observe for changes in the Picker

```
final class MyViewModel: ObservableObject {

    @Published var fieldType: String = ""

}
```

the problem is that I get the warning:

> Failed to produce diagnostic for expression; please submit a bug
> report (https://swift.org/contributing/#reporting-bugs) and include
> the project

whenever I try to reference my viewModel (`$viewModel.fieldType`). However if I change it to `.constant("Try")` the warning goes away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After seeing the declaration:

`struct AddEventView<ViewModel: AddEventViewModeling & ObservableObject>: View`

The only thing the compiler knows about the `ViewModel` type is that it is an `ObservableObject` and conforms to the `AddEventViewModeling` protocol (which you've not given us a definition for).

Specifically, the compiler has no idea that an instance of the type `ViewModel` should have a published property named `fieldType`.  So far as I know there is no way you could convey the existence of a published property in a protocol.

The end result is that the expression `$viewModel.fieldType` means nothing to the compiler and apparently confuses it so much that Swift doesn't have an error message to display for you.  Instead the Swift team left you a note asking you to report a bug.

Using the latest Xcode beta with your code, I get a diagnostic message:

`Value of type 'ObservedObject<ViewModel>.Wrapper' has no dynamic member 'fieldType' using key path from root type 'ViewModel'`

so later compilers apparently do a better job of recognizing and reporting the error.

When you give the compiler `.constant("Try")` it does know what that means and accepts it.

Elsewhere on you define `MyViewModel` to have a `fieldType` published property... but that's irrelevant to the generic type named `ViewModel` that is declared in the scope of `AddEventView`

Comment: Hey Scott! Thank you so much for your detailed answer. It is clear now what the compiler was complaining about. +1 for it! However, I found a way to silence the compiler keeping the conformance to my protocol. Please see my answer.

Comment: I have accepted the answer as my answer is a consequent of yours. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Scott Thompson's answer points me in the right direction.

As he correctly said, the compiler only knwew that the `ViewModel` type is that it is an `ObservableObject` and conforms to the `AddEventViewModeling` protocol.

`AddEventViewModeling` was declared as follows:

```
protocol AddEventViewModeling {
    // other properties
    var fieldType: String { get set }
    // other functions 
}
```

Looking at other people's code, who use the same approach for the view, I realized that adding `AnyObject` conformance to my protocol solved the issue.

```
protocol AddEventViewModeling: AnyObject {
    // other properties
    var fieldType: String { get set }
    // other functions 
}
```

Apple says:

> You use AnyObject when you need the flexibility of an untyped object
> or when you use bridged Objective-C methods and properties that return
> an untyped result. AnyObject can be used as the concrete type for an
> instance of any class, class type, or class-only protocol.

I honestly can't explain how this solve the issue but I am looking forward to hearing more from other fellow developers.